# Ruby set time zone *without Rails*

Tags: ruby, timezone

Is there any way for me to tell Ruby to use a certain time zone as if it were the local time zone?

TMI:

I realize that in Rails there is a lot of support for time zones, but I've just been put on a project which uses Ruby without Rails, and I need to fix a time zone in order to support some existing Rspec tests.

Among these tests are some calls to an FTP servIs there er with `Net::FTP`. The returned mtime is getting cast into my development machine's local time, breaking a number of existing specs.

Comment: Just ignore the accepted answer in the linked question but use the highest-voted answer instead. tl;dr: set the `TZ` environment variable to override the system-provided timezone for the current process.

Answer (score 1):

Not in STDLIB but you could use the `TZInfo` gem to accomplish this. They have a well written README.

Comment: Thanks. I have read the README, but I don't see a way to specify a system timezone. The only approach I see is to edit each of my specs to explicitly convert times from one  zone to another. Am I missing something?